# Silverlight: Auto Scrolling down with Scrollviewer

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a scrollviewer with dynamic content. On an event, a new content is made visible and the scrollbar appears. How do i make it auto scroll to have that content in view?

Thanks,
Shawn Mclean

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of the new content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ScrollToVerticalOffset()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx) to do this, passing in the coordinates of the new content.

```
var newContent = GetNewContent();

var generalTransform = newContent.TransformToVisual(
    Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);

Point offset = generalTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
double controlTop = offset.Y;
double controlLeft = offset.X;

scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffSet(controlTop);
scrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffSet(controlLeft);
```

Comment: render size does not give position.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure Scrollviewer is the control you need here?

Sounds to me like you ought to be using ListBox (which you can heavily style if necessary).  It has a `ScrollIntoView(item)` method which would acheive your goal.